# increases targetSdk: what to be aware of?

Tags: android

If all I want is for my app to function exactly the same when I increase the targetSdk (aside from the functionality I'm intentionally adding of course), is there any kind of comprehensive migration guide out there?

For example, I stumbled upon the fact that moving to api 13 'screen size' also changes when you change orientation, so I have to handle that if I don't want my activity to restart itself. I'd rather not find out these things the hard way after I've already pushed code...

Comment: http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/18/changes.html and just plug in the 18,17,16,15,14,13........ in the link for information about changes

Comment: yeah thats a whole ton of info tho, i'm looking for just some concise summary of the handful of things i need to watch out for to keep the same functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like for Android 4.2 and above, there is an "Important Behavior Changes" section in the API overview page, e.g. http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html. Unfortunately no such section appears for older releases even when there are important behavior changes compared to the previous version.